# JavaScript doesn't work in my browser but works in CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's very strange and, as I do not have much experience yet, I don't understand the problem of my JavaScript not working. I made a ToTop button.

In CodePen it works fine. As I scroll down it fades in & out. CodePen: http://bit.ly/1ttnjRi

But in Chrome it does nothing. Also, I sent all files to a friend and he had the same problem.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Debug console gives this: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

P.S. What is the purpose of down voting? Possibly I am not the only one newbie encountering this problem. I guess stackoverflow is for helping each other in the uneasy coding stuff, not bragging about knowing something more and because of that being arrogant. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: The first thing to do is bring up your JavaScript debug console.  In Chrome, you can do this by right clicking in the browser window and select "inspect element"  Then select console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: @BrianHoover it gives this - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: That usually means you're not including jQuery

Comment: Yep, you have no reference of jQuery in your page

Comment: Please replicate the code using **Code Snippet** feature on [so].

Comment: @nevermind As I mentioned, I'm not very experienced yet. Could you explain how to do it if it's not a long explanation?

Comment: Also your title makes no sense. Do you not open codepen in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery by adding this to your HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Included. No change. Still: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. The updated code - http://bit.ly/13wgnue

Comment: But the codepen was already fine, right? I mean in your local code you need to add this line. Now your codepen has two copies of jQuery.

Comment: My friend solved the problem using such method - <p> <a> <span></span> </a> </p>. And yes, codepen was fine, which was strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is you dependencies from the head tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/codeAcademy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, you are loading ../js/codeAcademy.js which uses jQuery, then you load jQuery library. You can't use jQuery until it's fully loaded.

Why this works on codepen? As you can see from the page source, codepen copied your script tags from head and pasted in the body and also created script tag in the bottom with your codeAcademy.js code. So when page loads it tries to load and execute codeAcademy.js and it fails, then it downloads jQuery and lastly it executed script from the bottom.

Also it's good habit to insert javascript in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Putting javascript at the bottom worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *$ not defined*, is jquery missing.But select the jquery version you have used to make the button, if you have selected **version 2.0** then stick with it for future works too.